# Why CASE WHEN always return 0 and 1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I use a table where there are two integer fields right_score and left_score. When CASE WHEN is used it outputs incorrect result :

```
SELECT 
    right_score,
    left_score,
    CASE
        WHEN right_score < 3 THEN right_score = 1
        WHEN right_score >= 3 THEN right_score = 0
    END AS r_result,
    CASE
        WHEN left_score < 3 THEN left_score = 1
        WHEN left_score >= 3 THEN left_score = 0
    END AS l_result
FROM
    de_data
WHERE
    id = 037629
```

The output shows right_score=0 , left_score=0, r_result=0 and l_result=0

But i expect the result as

The output shows right_score=0 , left_score=0, r_result=1 and l_result=1

Where did i went wrong ?

Comment: can you provide some sample data

Comment: You need `THEN 1` instead of `THEN right_score = 1`. And `THEN 0` instead of `THEN right_score = 0`

Comment: `left_score=1` is a boolean expression that returns 0 (false) since the value of `left_score` is not equal 1, as it is 0.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ : Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything is running as programmed.

So for  `right_score = 0`

```
WHEN right_score < 3 THEN right_score = 1
```

First MySQL checks if right_score is `smaller than three` and in the **next and second step** MySQL checks if right_score is `equal to 1` what is **false** which mysql tells by sending a 0

So in that line you have **two comparisons** and the result is what you have programmed a bunch of true(1) and false (0)

If you remove all the second comparisons, you get what you expected.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE de_data(id varchar(6),right_score int ,    left_score int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO de_data VALUES ('037629', 1,1),('037629', 3,1),('037629', 1,3),('037629', 3,3),('037629', 2,2)
> ,('037629', 1,1),('037629', 2,2)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     right_score,
>     left_score,
>     CASE
>         WHEN right_score < 3 THEN right_score = 1
>         WHEN right_score >= 3 THEN right_score = 0
>     END AS r_result,
>     CASE
>         WHEN left_score < 3 THEN left_score = 1
>         WHEN left_score >= 3 THEN left_score = 0
>     END AS l_result
> FROM
>     de_data
> WHERE
>     id = 037629
> ```

> ```
> right_score | left_score | r_result | l_result
> ----------: | ---------: | -------: | -------:
>           1 |          1 |        1 |        1
>           3 |          1 |        0 |        1
>           1 |          3 |        1 |        0
>           3 |          3 |        0 |        0
>           2 |          2 |        0 |        0
>           1 |          1 |        1 |        1
>           2 |          2 |        0 |        0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     right_score,
>     left_score,
>     CASE
>         WHEN right_score < 3 THEN  1
>         WHEN right_score >= 3 THEN  0
>     END AS r_result,
>     CASE
>         WHEN left_score < 3 THEN  1
>         WHEN left_score >= 3 THEN  0
>     END AS l_result
> FROM
>     de_data
> WHERE
>     id = 037629
> ```
>
> ```
> right_score | left_score | r_result | l_result
> ----------: | ---------: | -------: | -------:
>           1 |          1 |        1 |        1
>           3 |          1 |        0 |        1
>           1 |          3 |        1 |        0
>           3 |          3 |        0 |        0
>           2 |          2 |        1 |        1
>           1 |          1 |        1 |        1
>           2 |          2 |        1 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfddf769cd54ab1bb94895c70182b3d7)*

Comment: Try putting some other data that 1s in the right score column - eg 0 or -1 or 2 -  and it doesn't work.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Maybe i should have explained it better right_score = 1 is a comparison not a setting of values